# C++ Class Initialization Syntax and Error "does not name a type"

Tags: c++

I haven't touched C++ in a while and was hoping someone could point out where the problem is in my class definitions. I keep getting an error saying "error: ‘IPsource’ does not name a type".

```
class AddressPacket {
    std::string address;
    int packets;

    public:
    void initialize(std::string add) {
        address = add;
        packets = 1;
    }
    std::string getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    int getPackets() {
        return packets;
    }
    bool checkAddress(std::string add) {
        return address == add;
    }
    void addPacket() {
        packets++;
    }
};

class AddressPacketList {
    AddressPacket masterList[100];
    int listCounter;

    public:
    AddressPacketList() { listCounter = 0; }
    void add(std::string add) {
        masterList[listCounter].initialize(add);
        listCounter++;
    }
};
```

And then inside main I have...

```
AddressPacketList IPsource();
IPsource.add("Hello");
```

Comment: It's a case of [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't mean what you think it means:

```
AddressPacketList IPsource();
```

You think it declares an object named `IPsource` of type `AddressPacketList` and initializes it using `AddressPacketList`'s default constructor.

What it *actually* is is a function declaration.  You are declaring a function named `IPsource` which takes no parameters and returns a `AddressPacketList` object by-value.

This seemingly bizarre conclusion is the result of the so-called [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Simply change the line to:

```
AddressPacketList IPsource;
```

Comment: Removing the parentheses still results in a "does not name a type" error.

Comment: @Takkun:  Are you sure the error is exactly the same?  Please post the new error.  Also, are you `#include`ing everything needed?

Comment: It is the same "error: ‘IPsource’ does not name a type". I am defining the classes within the same class as the main function.

Comment: @Takkun:  What do you mean, "the same class as the main function?"  In C++, there is no `main` class -- there is only the `main` free function itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are declaring a function called `IPSource`, which returns a `AddressPacketList`:

```
AddressPacketList IPsource(); // parsed as function declaration
```

Then you try to use it as an object. You can fix it by changing the declaration to

```
AddressPacketList IPsource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AddressPacketList IPsource;
```

Only if you declare a variable and want to initialize it with a non-default constructor, you are allowed to use brackets. If you had a constructor like this:

```
AddressPacketList(std::string packet) { 
    masterList[0].initialize(packet);
    listCounter = 1; 
}
```

Then you could declare your local variable like this:

```
AddressPacketList IPsource("ABC");
```